# Quantity moves my "in stock"-label

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

The stockqty text (only 4 left) moves my in stock-label from being displayed beside the price.

Where would I go to make sure that the qty is shown below the label instead?

[image]

Comment: Do you have live url?

Comment: http://tiny.cc/2j633x

Comment: Looks like you are using some extension. Availability template resides in `catalog/product/view/availability/default.phtml`. All you need to do is bring `in stock` `<p>` tag before the `only 4 left` section, then you can do some css magic.